# Frobenius on projective variety is bijective but not an isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am working on exercise 1.8 from *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves (Silverman)*. I cannot figure out why $\phi$ is onto and why $\phi$ is not an isomorphism. The onto part is very strange for me. Thanks!

> Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field with $q$ elements and let $V \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a variety defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$.
>
> 1. Prove that the $q$th-power map $\phi = [X_0^q,\ldots,X_n^q]$ is a morphism $\phi : V \rightarrow V$. It is called the Frobenius
>      morphism.
> 2. Prove that $\phi$ is one-to-one and onto.
> 3. Prove that $\phi$ is not an isomorphism.
> 4. Prove that $V(\mathbb{F}_q) = \{P \in V : \phi(P) = P\}$.

Comment: Try a small example to see why this happens. In fact, you can even take $V=\mathbb P^n$ and $n=1$, and you cannot go simpler than that!

Comment: For the surjectivity: the points come from (I assume -- it has been a while since I read this part of AEC) an algebraically closed field. So every $[a_0,\dots,a_n] \in V$ is of the form $[b_0^q,\dots,b_n^q]$. The goal is to show that $[b_0,\dots,b_q] \in V$. Okay, so each homogeneous polynomial in a generating set for the ideal defining $V$ has to vanish on this tuple. Stare at this condition for a while. It's absolutely crucial that $V$ is defined over $\mathbf{F}_q$.

Comment: @Hoot   Thanks! It is very clear. And do you have any idea about the third part? I am considering that maybe I can show the coordinate ring of V and $\phi$(V) is not same. Does it work?

Comment: @qwwwqq One can show, in fact, that frobenius is an isomorphism if and only if $V$ is so-called 'étale'—a finite separable extension of $\mathbb{F}_q$. The key is to show that if $V$ is smooth of dimension $n$ then the Frobenius map is finite flat of degree $q^n$. One does this by 'devissage' to $\mathbb{A}^n$. I don't recall what Silverman assumes, so tell me if any of this sounds familiar. In simpler terms, you should check that the map is not étale by computing its Jacobian.

Comment: Frobenius preserves the standard affine cover of $\mathbf P^n$, so you should be able to reduce to the affine case.